# Inserting a carriage return for data in a Google Spreadsheets/Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to take some values from a google spreadsheet.  Using a script, I would like to take each cell value and put a carriage return in after it, so that I can put them into a list form on a google doc.  This is the code that I am using in my script.

```
var sh11 = sh0.getRange('O2:O10').getValues().forEach() + ",\n\n\";
```

If I run it as it is written, I get the error message of "TypeError: (class)@2f0e9973 is not a function, it is undefined."  If I modify it to this:

```
var sh11 = sh0.getRange('O2:O10').getValues().forEach();
```

Then it runs, but clumps the output all together, like this example.

If my column values are this:

```
O2 Waffles
O3 Pancakes
O4 Eggs
O5 Toast
```

I am getting Waffles, Pancakes, Eggs, Toast as the output.

I would like the doc to look like this:

```
Waffles
Pancakes
Eggs
Toast
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
I found a way for it to work like this.

```
var sh11 = sh0.getRange('O2:O10').getValues()
var multiLine ="";

for (var i = 0; i <= sh11.length - 1; i++) 
{
multiLine += sh11[i]+"\n";
}

var d = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = d.getBody();

body.replaceText('ThisText',multiLine);
```

Comment: Hi @nwill001  I gave it a try and it gave me the same result of clumping the output all together.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I may need more details if you can. Where and how are you outputting it?

Comment: Hi @nwill001.  What is happening is that I have a google form that I have created.  The spreadsheet is linked to that.  Within the spreadsheet, I query the date using this code `=QUERY(B2:D1008; "select * where B = date '" & text(M2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")`  If the data for the day matches the date, it moves all the data in rows C and D to rows O and P.  When I run my script on the spreadsheet, it looks to row O for the values, and then the output goes to a google doc template which is filled in based on the variables.  I hope that helps.  Paul

Comment: Can you show me how you are putting it in the document?

Comment: Okay, so here is what I think you are asking for

Comment: 'var docTemplate = "16VEbdE_iPADyPTYChQvbPNW70LZi4SjZxmRD6Cp4YQU" ; // This is a link to the google template 
var docName = "Morning Announcements" ; // This is what it will be called

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var sh11 = sh0.getRange('O2:O10').getValues();

for (var i = 0; i <= sh11.length - 1; i++) 
{
var array1 = [{}];
array1[i] = sh11[i][0].split(" ");
Logger.log(array1[i][1]);
}

var email_address = "pthompson@ucc.on.ca"; // This is the receivers email address.

var announcement3 = sh11;'

Comment: Part2 '  
// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+ date)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyAnnouncement3', announcement3);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();'

Comment: Part3 '// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Morning Announcements";
var body = "Here are the morning announcements for " + date + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}'

Comment: First I noted copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();. getActiveSection() is now .getBody() I believe.

Comment: I edited my answer. I found a way to get this to work.

Comment: Hi.  I had a look at this, and I think I understand most of it, except the part where you call the active document.  When I tried that part I received a TypeError: Cannot call method "getBody" of null.  Am I trying to call the doc template that I am using?

Comment: In your code simply replace the `var announcement3 = sh11;` with `var announcement3 = ""; 
  
for (var i = 0; i <= sh11.length - 1; i++) 
{
announcement3 += sh11[i]+"\n";
}` And you can remove that array1 for loop as well.

Comment: Quick question.  When I run this, if the cells are empty, it just puts in a , and then moves to the next line and does it again.  I could end up with One value, and then 9 commas underneath it.  Is there a way to suppress the empty ones?

Answer (score 0):

The method `forEach()` takes a function as an argument, and that function is applied to each item in the array. The code below should do what you want, and uses `forEach()` and `join()` to get the result.

```
function getValuesAsList(range, rowSeparator, columnSeparator) {
  var values = range.getValues();
  var output = values.map(function(row) {
    return row.join(columnSeparator);
  }).join(rowSeparator);
  return output;
}

function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A3');
  var list = getValuesAsList(range, '\n', ', ');
  Logger.log(list);
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric.  I would like to try this.  Would it be possible for you to break it down a little for me?  I am a little unsure as to how it all works.  Thank you.  Paul

Comment: Try running the test() function and changing the ranges. The best way to learn is by doing!